# `React/RCTBridgeModule.h` file not found

Tags: ios, xcode, reactjs, native, react-native-ios

Getting this error while building a react-native iOS app on xcode.

[image]

Started getting this error after npm install and rpm linking [react-native-fs](https://github.com/johanneslumpe/react-native-fs) library. But after searching online for a solution, I noticed that many people are getting the same error while installing other react native libraries.

A **possible solution** suggested by many is, 
Adding the following under "Build Settings" -> "Header Search Paths".

`$(SRCROOT)/../node_modules/react-native/React` - (Recursive)

But no luck with this solution, still getting the same error

Comment: I'm getting this same error with v0.41.2, it should work with <React/RCT...> but it doesn't :/

Comment: @camou see my answer below; it may help

Comment: @CecilRodriguez What version do you have for react-native-fs?. If you are manually adding with XCode please check https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs#adding-manually-in-xcode

Comment: I am getting this error :Unable to resolve module `react-native-webrtc`

Comment: If you've having M1 chip then this should fix it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/68275769/2643815

Comment: A pod update was the fix for me.

Comment: I our case we've get same error in two Macs with M1 cpu, and the solution to run the App was through Xcode going to Product, Destination, Destination Architecture and choose Show Rosetta destination. After that, the error stay but the App start running in emulator.

Answer (score 169, accepted):

In my case this particular problem happened when I was trying to archive a 0.40+ react-native app for iOS (solution was found here: [Reliable build on `^0.39.2` fails when upgrading to `^0.40.0`](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11721#issuecomment-270672904)).

What happened was that ***Xcode*** was trying to build the react-native libraries in parallel and was building libraries with implicit react dependencies *before* actually building the react library.

The solution in my case was to:

1. Disable the parallel builds:

   - Xcode menu -> Product -> Scheme -> Manage Shemes...
   - Double click on your application
   - Build tab -> uncheck Parallelize Build
2. Add react as a project dependecy

   - Xcode Project Navigator -> drag React.xcodeproj from Libraries to root tree
   - Build Phases Tab -> Target Dependencies -> + -> add **React**

Comment: I have discovered that this only happens when you're upgrading to react-native 0.40+ from below. Project that are initilized with the 0.40+ RN already have parallel builds turned off.

Comment: What does "drag to root tree" mean?  And the "Build Phases Tab" ... is this the Build Phases of React.xcodeproj?

Comment: When this bug appears after creation of a new target, step 1 is enough :)

Comment: When adding React as a target dependency, make sure to add it ABOVE your app as described in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52425997/4744177

Comment: How do you deal with an Expo ejected project? I don't have React.xcodeproj anywhere, React is in Podfile dependencies

Comment: @SebastienLorber open node_modules and drag react project from there

Comment: For expo, copy the the file from `PROJECT_ROOT/node_modules/react-native/React/React.xcodeproj` @SebastienLorber

Comment: Why should I disable parallel builds to fix this issue, I've to use that feature to reduce the build time. any other solution?

Comment: This fixed it for me, but here is the clarification:

Comment: can anyone clarify what does "drag React.xcodeproj from Libraries to root tree" mean.

Comment: The tree has a Libraries subfolder where the React.xcodeproj is - you need to move it to the root of the tree which you can via drag-and-drop.

Comment: No it doesnt have a libraries sub folder

Comment: As  React Native 0.64, there is no React.xcodeproj file anymore

Comment: @Lopakhin - then how does one solve this issue for react-native  > 0.64? I am having this exact issue and cannot find a solution.

Comment: There is no Build tab -> uncheck Parallelize Build any more but the bug is still there!

Answer (score 36):

Make sure you disable `Parallelise Build` and add `React` target above your target

[image]

Comment: Figured it out on my own after the first answer, but moving react up did the trick! Had to realize what that actually meant for the building process though

Comment: Was pulling my hair out and thinking what I was doing wrong after adding the React target but moving it up did the trick. @njoye could you explain what this means in the build process? Thank you!

Comment: @EugeneKim the order of elements in lists is Apple's way of showing chronological order (this still f*s me up often, on OSX as well as iOS). So putting the target "React" before "App" will build the code from "React" before your own. Since your own code uses the React target this seems to affect if it is able to be built. There are probably files being built that are then used in your target.

Comment: I want to use the parallel build feature to reduce the build time

Answer (score 32):

QUICK FIX (not the best)

Change the import react-native header lines:

```
 #import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>
 #import <React/RCTLog.h>
```

To:

```
 #import "RCTBridgeModule.h"
 #import "RCTLog.h"
```

Here is an example of changes I had to make for the library I was trying to use: [Closes #46 - 'RCTBridgeModule.h' file not found](https://github.com/johanneslumpe/react-native-fs/pull/238/files).

Comment: If you read the release notes carefully, I think it's actually the other way -- the new / approved way is `#import <React/RCT...h>`? [commit here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/e1577df1fd70049ce7f288f91f6e2b18d512ff4d)

Comment: I know it seems backwards to what the docs recommend, but the specified format `#import "RCTBridgeModule.h"` really did work better for me today.

Comment: The error for me is flagged in the file RCTFileReaderModule.h.
I changed the #import statement as suggested but it didn't help.
I see in the linked repo pull request that the change was done in RNFSManager.h and RNFSManager.m. I tried making it in these two files but it didn't help either.
Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: But my code is erroring out at `#import "RCTBridgeModule.h"`...

Comment: [0.71] Do not use this method, all subsequent imports inside `React/*.h` now fails with not found.

Comment: Thanks, this is the only working solution for React-native react-native > 0.64. Worked with my 0.66.5 project.

Answer (score 16):

Change

```
  #import "RCTBridgeModule.h"
```

to

```
 #import "React/RCTBridgeModule.h"
```

Answer (score 4):

If `Libraries/React.xcodeproj` are red in xcode then reinstall node_modules

```
rm -rf node_modules && yarn
```

My newly created project from react-native 0.46.3 was red :S I have npm 5.3.0 and yarn 0.24.5 when I did react-native init

Comment: Thank you, i was pushing my project to github. And when cloning it again i was missing the React libraries that were showing in red.
your command is working. 

Answer (score 4):

For me, this error occurred when I added a new scheme/target (**app.staging**) in the app and installed pods using pod install.

This issue is occurring due to pods are not shared for all targets. So I need to add newly added target (**app.staging**) inside the **Podfile**.

Here is my Podfile.

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

target 'app' do
  # Pods for app
  pod 'FBLazyVector', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBLazyVector"
  pod 'FBReactNativeSpec', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBReactNativeSpec"

  target 'appTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  # Pods for staging app // important line below
  target 'app.staging'

  use_native_modules!
end
```

Comment: Helped me! I needed also to clean project after pod install

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this issue after doing a manual `react-native link` of a dependency which didn't support auto link on RN 0.59+

The solution was to select the xcodeproj file under the Libraries folder in Xcode and then in Build Settings, change Header Search Paths to add these two (recursive):

```
$(SRCROOT)/../../../ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-Core
$(SRCROOT)/../../../ios/Pods/Headers/Public
```

Comment: this solved my problem, I think the old solutions(linking React.xcodeproj etc) don't work anymore, this one is the correct solution.

Comment: That worked for me too, wasted some time on this one.. Should be the selected answer in 2022 when humanity divided to projects in > 0.59 and < 0.59

Answer (score 4):

My solution was to remove everything in `Libraries` like described [here](https://github.com/react-native-community/upgrade-support/issues/14)

Comment: This worked for me, thank you so much! By the way, @redexp if possible can you please explain what was the issue exactly? Because I have no idea about cocoapods and xcode

Answer (score 3):

For viewers who got this error after upgrading React Native to 0.40+, you may need to run `react-native upgrade` on the command line.

Comment: I'm trying this right now. What about using [react-native-git-upgrade](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/react-native-git-upgrade) instead?

Comment: Right, that's the other option. I think they'll both work.

Answer (score 3):

- delete the pods folder and the .xcworkspace file
- run pod install again in that directory
- try to archive again and done

Answer (score 2):

Latest releases of react-native libraries as explained in previous posts and [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.40.0) have breaking compatibility changes. If you do not plan to upgrade to react-native 0.40+ yet you can force install previous version of the library, for example with react-native-fs:

```
npm install --save -E react-native-fs@1.5.1
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to build a debug, but I was unable to build an archive.

I solved this issue by dragging `React.xcodeproj` found in /node_modules/react-native/React to my root directory in Xcode, then added React as a target dependancy in build phases > target dependencies.

Comment: There's no `React.xcodeproj` in `/node_modules/react-native/React`.

Comment: @AndrewKoster I am experiencing the same issue

Comment: @CecilRodriguez I've managed to fix this when compiling in Xcode, by adding Cocoapods and adding React as a pod in the Podfile. However, once I try to use the compiled library in `react-native run-ios`, I get compilation errors that don't happen in Xcode. The complete lack of relevant documentation is frustrating.

Comment: @CecilRodriguez  have you found a solution?

Comment: @AndrewKoster so inside Xcode it does work? If it does, can you explain in more details what you did?

Comment: @Yossi No, not yet. All of the attempts I've tried haven't worked.

Comment: @Yossi No, I tried yours. No luck. It has something to do with my native module I think

Answer (score 2):

After React Native 0.60 this issue is often caused by a linked library mixed with the new 'auto-linking' feature. This fixes it for me

Unlink old library using

```
$ react-native unlink react-native-fs
```

Refresh Pods integration entirely using

```
$ pod deintegrate && pod install
```

Now reload your workspace and do a clean build.

Answer (score 2):

I receive this error in any new module I create with [create-react-native-module](https://github.com/brodybits/create-react-native-module/). None of the posted solutions worked for me.

What worked for me was first making sure to run `yarn` in the newly created module folder in order to create `node_modules/` (this step is probably obvious). Then, in XCode, select Product -> Scheme -> React instead of the default selection of MyModuleName.

Comment: +1, it's important to add for others new to module development that you won't see the other schemes until you create a valid podfile and run `pod install`. create-react-native-module does not appear to do this for you. Got me hung up for a while. But this worked for me once I created a valid podfile and ran the install.

Comment: @ElliotRodriguez is the Podfile from the example/ios folder acceptable for a library itself?

Answer (score 1):

This error appeared for me after I ran `pod install` command for the new dependencies. Along with those, React had also been installed. Therefore probably Xcode was confused for path. I removed these lines from PodFile and error was gone. Please note that those removed from here were already linked in Xcode.

```
target 'app' do

  pod 'GoogleMaps'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth', '~> 6.3.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Database', '~> 6.3.0'

  # Removed four pods below and it worked.

  pod 'react-native-image-picker', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-image-picker'

  pod 'ReactNativePermissions', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-permissions'

  pod 'react-native-image-resizer', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-image-resizer'

  pod 'RNFS', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-fs'

  end
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to iOS folder in your project and install pod -

```
$ pod install
```

If you are getting any error in installation of pod type command-

```
$ xcode-select -p
```

Result should be - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer

If the path is incorrect then open your iOS project in Xcode and go to: Xcode->preferences->command line tools-> select Xcode

And again install the pod your issue will be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

anhdevit's suggestion in https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/24363#issuecomment-488547280 worked for me:

`In your terminal, run:
     defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it from your editor also open **SMobile.xcscheme**

And change `parallelizeBuildables = "NO"`

Answer (score 0):

For me didn't work any from the above solutions and below it is what worked (I had already checked out `Parallelize Build` and added `React`)

```
1. Open XCode --> To Libraries add `$LibraryWhichDoesNotWork.xcodeproj$`
2. Then for your app in the `Build Phases` add to the `Link Binary with Libraries` the file `lib$LibraryWhichDoesNotWork$.a`
```

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this issue while upgrading from 0.58.4 to new react-native version 0.60.4. Nothing from what i found on the internet helped me, but I managed to get it working:

**Go to build settings, search for 'Header search paths', select the entry, press DELETE button.**

I had these values overriden, and looks like they fell back to defaults after deletion. Also Cocoapods was complaining about it with messages in Terminal after `pod install`:

```
[!] The `app [Release]` target overrides the `HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-app/Pods-app.release.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep Parallelise Build enabled and avoid the missing header problems, then provide a pre-build step in your scheme to put the react headers into the derived-data area. Notice the build settings are coming from the React project in this case.  Yes it's not a thing of beauty but it gets the job done and also shaves a lot of time off the builds. The prebuild step output ends up in prebuild.log.  The exact headers you'll need to copy over will depend on your project react-native dependencies, but you'll get the jist from this.

[image: Edit Scheme => Build]

Get the derived data directory from the environment variables and copy the required react headers over.

```
#build_prestep.sh (chmod a+x)
derived_root=$(echo $SHARED_DERIVED_FILE_DIR|sed 's/DerivedSources//1')
react_base_headers=$(echo $PROJECT_FILE_PATH|sed 's#React.xcodeproj#Base/#1')
react_view_headers=$(echo $PROJECT_FILE_PATH|sed 's#React.xcodeproj#Views/#1')
react_modules_head=$(echo $PROJECT_FILE_PATH|sed 's#React.xcodeproj#Modules/#1')
react_netw_headers=$(echo $PROJECT_FILE_PATH|sed 's#React/React.xcodeproj#Libraries/Network/#1')
react_image_header=$(echo $PROJECT_FILE_PATH|sed 's#React/React.xcodeproj#Libraries/Image/#1')

echo derived root = ${derived_root}
echo react headers = ${react_base_headers}

mkdir -p ${derived_root}include/React/

find  "${react_base_headers}" -type f -iname "*.h" -exec cp {} "${derived_root}include/React/" \;
find  "${react_view_headers}" -type f -iname "*.h" -exec cp {} "${derived_root}include/React/" \;
find  "${react_modules_head}" -type f -iname "*.h" -exec cp {} "${derived_root}include/React/" \;
find  "${react_netw_headers}" -type f -iname "*.h" -exec cp {} "${derived_root}include/React/" \;
find  "${react_image_header}" -type f -iname "*.h" -exec cp {} "${derived_root}include/React/" \;
```

The script does get invoked during a build-clean - which is not ideal. In my case there is one env variable which changes letting me exit the script early during a clean.

```
if [ "$RUN_CLANG_STATIC_ANALYZER" != "NO" ] ; then
    exit 0 
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

react-native version 0.67.4  (recently updated)  This build error started to show up in ios.

I found under my project > Edit Scheme > Build

There was a reference to "React" but it indicated "Missing"

So I removed it (little - button) and added React back (little + button) via the popup which has a Pods folder and a "React" pod project present.

So it looks like react-native used to supply a project file that you would set as a build target in the scheme: /node_modules/react-native/ReactReact.xcodeproj

However with this newer version of react that project is not present, which would explain why building will fail if you have a native module bridge (its searching for header files that don't exist)

I no longer get the build error, but I haven't verified it works.  Will update once I get a positive outcome (or a negative one for that matter).  Even if this does fix it, I am not sure if this is the "right" way, but I'm certainly open to suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the wrong target was selected in podfile, after correcting that, I was good to go.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I removed the 'arm64' from the release section located under Excluded architectures in the targets project

Answer (score -3):

What you can do to get it right is:

1) `npm uninstall reat-native-fs` to uninstall library

2)`npm unlink react-native-fs` to unlink the library

Now the library is successfully removed and now install the lib again in your project and this time link everything manually. Sometime automatic linking causes this error.