# React Native ios build error 'React/RCTBridgeModule.h' file not found

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, build, node-modules

I am unable to build react native ios build for real devices and simiulator. Facing following issue:

> "'React/RCTBridgeModule.h
>   ' file not found".

Any solutions?

Comment: You can check this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41663002/react-rctbridgemodule-h-file-not-found may be this help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [\`React/RCTBridgeModule.h\` file not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41663002/react-rctbridgemodule-h-file-not-found)

Comment: were you able to find a solution? none of the links to the other "solutions" worked fo me.

Comment: Didn't work for me either. @lsimonetti  have you found a solution?

Answer (score -2):

Change the import react-native header lines:

```
 #import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>
 #import <React/RCTLog.h>
```

To

```
 #import "RCTBridgeModule.h"
 #import "RCTLog.h"
```