# 'RCTSwiftBridgeModule.h' file not found

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Getting this error `'RCTSwiftBridgeModule.h' file not found` while building my react-native project for ios.

I have tried solutions mentioned in ['React/RCTBridgeModule.h' file not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41663002/react-rctbridgemodule-h-file-not-found) but not successful to fix it.

Xcode: 10.3

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved it by following these steps.

1. delete all node modules
2. clear the cache
3. delete `DerivedData` directory from `~/Library/Developer/Xcode`
4. Reinstall the node_modules
5. Run the project