# After run pod install react get removed while upgrading react-native version

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, podfile, podfile-lock

Can anyone explain why the pod install removing the React. Also it shows the React missing in product-->Edit scheme.

I need any good solution

RCTBrigeModule.h file not found error?

I dont have any idea how to fix this.

> Before unlinking the package and not run pod install

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'
pod 'Fabric'
pod 'Crashlytics'

target 'App' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  # Pods for App

  target 'App-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
    pod 'rn-fetch-blob', :path => '../node_modules/rn-fetch-blob'

    pod 'BVLinearGradient', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-linear-gradient'

    pod 'RNVectorIcons', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons'
    pod 'RNImageCropPicker', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-image-crop-picker'

    pod 'react-native-camera', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-camera'

    pod 'RNImageRotate', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-image-rotate'

    pod 'RNShare', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-share'

    pod 'RNViewShot', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-view-shot'

    pod 'RNFS', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-fs'

    pod 'BugsnagReactNative', :path => '../node_modules/bugsnag-react-native'

    pod 'RNGestureHandler', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler'

    pod 'react-native-webview', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-webview'

  end

  target 'AppTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

> After linking and run pod install

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'
pod 'Fabric'
pod 'Crashlytics'

target 'App' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  # Pods for App

  target 'App-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing


  end

  target 'AppTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

Comment: Are you trying to upgrade to 0.60+?

Comment: Yes, I am trying for more than one week

Comment: I have a general question about a huge file generated after upgrade.

After react-native upgrade I found huge files like ios/Index/Datasource/some thing....

What is the use of this files. Shall I need to commit this or need to move in .gitignore.

Can you explain why it get generated?

Answer (score 0):

If you trying to to upgrade to v0.60+, you have to do this manually with this tool.
(https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/). There is many breaking changes including pod support and androidX support.

Update all libraries to latest version, remove all manual linked libraries before RN upgrade from Xcode, to avoid Xcode crashes.

This article may help https://reactnative.thenativebits.com/courses/upgrading-react-native/upgrade-to-react-native-0.60/

Comment: I am getting this error  No podspec found for `BugsnagReactNative` in `../node_modules/bugsnag-react-native`

Comment: Can you post your Podfile?

Comment: updated in my podfile in my question which is under Before unlinking the package and not run pod install. Additionally I am added   use_native_modules! below the AppTests target

Comment: do you try this answer(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41663002/react-rctbridgemodule-h-file-not-found)

Comment: @Lenoarod It not work for me. Did you know any solution for the Link Binaries Framework not shows lib folder instead of it shows Frameworks

Comment: @sejn you can try this answer(https://stackoverflow.com/a/43340802/5705408), and you should show the error info, which library shows that when you see the build info. in my situation, it is react-native-contact.

Comment: @Lenoarod i have fixed above by removing use frameworks from the Podfile

Comment: I am getting 'React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h' file not found in AppDelegate.m file

Comment: @Lenoarod Can you confirm after upgrading how your Header Seach Paths are. Is it like (${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/BugsnagReactNative") this? Or ($RCTROOT/filename)

Comment: I have a general question about a huge file generated after upgrade.

After react-native upgrade I found huge files like ios/Index/Datasource/some thing....

What is the use of this files. Shall I need to commit this or need to move in .gitignore.

Can you explain why it get generated?