# 'React/RCTBridgeDelegate.h' file not found - React Native

Tags: ios, react-native

I am new to react native and have been creating a new app. I tried to update my project from react native 0.60 to 0.63. When doing this I had to create a new project file in order to update my cocoapods. After doing this I tired to run my app on an iOS emulator but am given an error.

When opening my project within Xcode I am given the following error.

[image: error]

I am not sure if this has to do with my pods or not. After doing some research online I am unable to find the answer to this problem.

Here is my profile file.

```html
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
 platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'Example' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Example

  target 'ExampleTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end

target 'Example-tvOS' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Example-tvOS

  target 'Example-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension' do
    # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
    use_frameworks!
  
    # Pods for OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension
    pod 'OneSignal', '>= 2.9.3', '< 3.0'
  end

end
```

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41663002/react-rctbridgemodule-h-file-not-found

Comment: already tried this but it didn't fix the problem

Comment: I got the same issue and 8 months with no fix still

Answer (score 0):

in my case, the problem was that Xcode had a different iOS than Podfile. As an example:
Yours is:
`platform :ios, '10.0'`

But in Xcode might be a different one

[image: Tab General on My target with IOS 11.0]

Comment: it not work for me

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I open the wrong xcode file to launch the build.

I had the RCTBridgeDelegate.h file not found while building with xcodeproj but the build was successful with the xcworkspace

Hope this will save some souls haha

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).