# How to create a Xcode workspace for a Turbo Module in React Native

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode, react-native

I'm following the guide here to create a Native Module in React Native. I selected Swift & Kotlin for the language.

https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-setup

I go through the setup, and it creates two projects. One is an example app and the top level is a library project (AwesomeModule.xcodeproj) for the module. When I open up the iOS library project for the Turbo Module in Xcode I get this errors.

> 'React/RCTBridgeModule.h' file not found

Here is a screenshot of that directory. It just generates a project file without a workspace.

[image]

How do I generate a Workspace in this library project so I can run it independently of the example project?

Comment: are you trying to open `xcodeproj` file? I believe you should be opening `xcworkspace`

Comment: There's no workspace generated with the native module project. I added a screenshot.

Comment: There are so many reasons for this error really. For example look at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41663002/react-rctbridgemodule-h-file-not-found - at least 4-5 different reasons. So without further details / debug details, nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: The problem I'm having is most of these solutions and suggestions are from several years ago. This should be easily reproducible. I tried on multiple machines with the steps in my post and I get the same results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for making a library, we don't need to make `xcworkspace` separately for a library or native modules, for pod support in your library or native modules you can use `project_root/project.podspec`

I would suggest using [react-native-builder-bob](https://github.com/callstack/react-native-builder-bob) for creating native turbo modules with an example folder. it is easy to use

```
npx create-react-native-library@latest react-native-awesome-library
```

[image]